# Target a Document Library Event Receiver to a Library with a Space in the URL

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, xml

See XML below.  When I attempt to activate the feature I get the error "The list "Test List" doesn't exist.  Please fix the ListUrl attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Test List">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>DocumentFactoryItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>DocumentSupport.EventReceivers.DocumentFactory.DocumentFactory</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix was to use an XML space escape for the library name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Test&#032;List">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>DocumentFactoryItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>DocumentSupport.EventReceivers.DocumentFactory.DocumentFactory</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```